# QGIS DataPlotly plugin

Tags: plugins, plotly, qgis

I have just installed the QGIS data plotly plugin V4.1.0
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DataPlotly/

At present it only seems to have the scatter plot. No boxplot or anything else.

I am using QGIS 3.28.4

Anyone else have similar problem?  The plugin was updated on November 15, so wondering if its a temporary issue.